# JavaScript code is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to code it, as if when I untick the check box both drop down menu's should become read only, but currently only the second drop down menu becomes read only, the first one does not become read only and remains editable, What is the problem here? Why is the first drop down not becoming read only upon unticking the check box?

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("1").disabled = false;
    }
    
    function mySecondFunction() {
     var ddl = document.getElementById("1");
     var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selectedValue == "ExceptionZero")
       {
        document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
     //set default
     document.getElementById("mySelection").value = "OptionZero"
       }else {
        document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
       }
     
    }
    
    function myThirdFunction(){
     document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
     //set default 
     document.getElementById("mySelection").value = "OptionZero"
     
     //first drop down 
     document.getElementById("1").disabled = true;
     document.getElementById("1").value = "OptionZero"
    }
    
    </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectionbox" value="Yes" onclick="myFunction()" onchange="myThirdFunction()"/>
    
    <select disabled id="1" onchange="mySecondFunction()">
        <option value="OptionZero">Default</option>
        <option value="OptionOne">Car</option>
        <option value="OptionTwo">Car2</option>
        <option value="OptionThree">Car23</option>
    </select>
    <br>
     <select disabled id="mySelection">
        <option value="OptionZero">Default</option>
        <option value="OptionOne">A</option>
        <option value="OptionTwo">B</option>
        <option value="OptionThree">C</option>
     </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: why are you using two functions onclick and onchange. Cant you use one ?

Comment: Because myFunction is being called onclick and this happens after the onchange event, so you're always setting disabled to false every time you click on the checkbox.

Comment: I'm not sure, if the firing order of the events (click and change) would be the same in different browsers. Anyway, you should use only one event to detect the change, usually it's `click` on checkbox, since `change` doesn't fire immediately in all browsers.

Comment: With a purely JS/HTML question like this, a provided JSFiddle would be beneficial as to not require potential answerers from having to do it themselves :P

Comment: [A fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoLdkhz/1/).

Comment: Id's should not be numbers nor start with a number: it won't work

Comment: @chiapa While not starting with numbers is good practice and won't work in older versions of HTML, HTML 5 does not have this restriction.

Comment: Thanks @JGrice, I wasn't aware of that. I'm so used to it being a mistake that I pointed it out as one.

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick event is called again after the onChange event, causing box 1 to enable. Try changing your onclick to this and removing your thirdFunction event.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tn3Lw2m/)

```
function myFunction() {   
        if (document.getElementById("1").disabled == false) {
            document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
            //set default 
            document.getElementById("mySelection").value = "OptionZero"

            //first drop down 
            document.getElementById("1").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("1").value = "OptionZero"    
        } else {
            document.getElementById("1").disabled = false;
        }
    }
```

The order of event calls can vary by browser, so you should only have one event when the order makes a difference to the output.